# JavaFX with Netbeans, how to implement MVC Pattern

Tags: model-view-controller, netbeans, javafx-8

I use Netbeans and the JavaFX Application Template. That creates just one Class. How do I implement the design pattern MVC for JavaFX. I want to create the GUI in seperate class and a ControllerClass for all EventHandlers.
It would be perfect if someone could show me using of MVC with this easy code. Thanks a lot!!

```
public class JavaFXMVC extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: Try the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/fxml_tutorial.htm)

Comment: You should use the new project->javafx->javafx fxml application template

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know about the this possibility. But I would prefer to to a MVC with my java-Code.